Set up DBMS connection read timeout interval with SQL?
Can I set this up using SQL only? I know that this can be changed in the Workbench and that works in my dev environment, but in live I won't have access to the workbench, so I need to do this in a .sql file.
I just want to change this setting, run a procedure that takes a looong time and revert it back to its original value.
I tried setting up connect_timeout, interactive_timeout, wait_timeout, net_write_timeout to the value I want but it does not do anything, I still get the same error:
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 
